# Amazon Echo Playing Music on Command

Tags: javascript, audio, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

Hey everyone so I'm having a difficult time trying to implement an audio playback. Here's the [docs](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-audioplayer-interface-reference)


So what I really want to do seems quite simple but came out to be very confusing where everything is suppose to go.

I want to be able to say a command. Alexa will respond will a little outputSpeech and then proceed to play a small audio track mp3 that I would provide. I don't mind uploading it locally(When I zip the files and import them into a lamda function) or using S3 Buckets SDK to stream the mp3 file. Which ever is easier for you guys.

Here's what I got so far.

With the codes below I'm able to get Alexa to respond to be voice and output a speech.

**I'm only using the IntentRequest to reduce codes for you guys.**

- I'm going to say "Alexa open myApp and play my music"
- "play my music" is the command i'm going to list as my utterance when I set up my skill in the alexa developer console

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        if (event.request.type === 'IntentRequest') {
            onIntent(event.request,
                event.session,
                (sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) => {
                    callback(null, buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
                });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

**My function that will be called when the Intent request goes through**

- My intent name will be **PlayMyMusic**

```
function onIntent(intentRequest, session, callback) {
    console.log(`onIntent requestId=${intentRequest.requestId}, sessionId=${session.sessionId}`);

    const intent = intentRequest.intent;
    const intentName = intentRequest.intent.name;

    if (intentName === 'PlayMyMusic') {
        PlayMyMusic(intent, session, callback);
    } else if (intentName === 'AMAZON.StopIntent' || intentName === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent') {
        handleSessionEndRequest(callback);
    } else {
        throw new Error('Invalid intent');
    }
}
```

**This is the output Message**

```
function PlayMyMusic(intent, session, callback) {

    const repromptText = null;
    const sessionAttributes = {};
    let shouldEndSession = true;
    let speechOutput = '';

        speechOutput = `I'm Alexa and I will output speech in this area. After I'm done talking I will play an audio track`;

    callback(sessionAttributes,
        buildSpeechletResponse(intent.name, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
}
```

**This is my simple Intent Schema**

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "PlayMyMusic"
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
   }
  ]
}
```

**Sample Utterances**

```
PlayMyMusic play my music
```

Everything works as of right now where Amazon can talk to me back and end the session.

How would I be able to have Amazon responds to me and then play some audio? The docs are kind of not working for me.

Where do I put the play directive? (AudioPlayer.Play)

Comment: have you got your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SSML and add mp3 path at any https url and it will play song

[see this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio)

```
Include the audio tag within your text-to-speech response within the speak tag. Alexa plays the MP3 at the specified point within the text to speech. For example:
<speak>
    Welcome to Car-Fu. 
    <audio src="soundbank://soundlibrary/transportation/amzn_sfx_car_accelerate_01" /> 
    You can order a ride, or request a fare estimate. 
    Which will it be?
</speak> 
When Alexa renders this response, it would sound like this:
Alexa: Welcome to Car-Fu.
(the specified amzn_sfx_car_accelerate_01.mp3 audio file plays)
Alexa: You can order a ride, or request a fare estimate. Which will
```

Comment: Can you please add any example for the same?

Comment: Please check this https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio